# Trabalhar no html dentro de uma variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma variável que contém uma string com um código HTML, dentro desse código eu tenho alguns `<input type="text">`. O que eu estou precisando e não consegui encontrar solução, é alterar o `value` desses `inputs`(quantidade de inputs varia) dentro dessa variável.

Eu basicamente queria fazer algo assim:

```
$("input[type=text][name=" + i + "]").val();
```

a única diferença é que quero fazer isso com o HTML que está dentro da variável `var html`

Comment: Você selecionou este html com o jquery o ele é um string com o código html?

Comment: @WictorChaves é uma string que contem o HTML, puxa esse html do banco de dados

Comment: Seria uma boa você postar na pergunta como é o HTML que está nesta variável e o que pode variar nela, pois podem haver classes IDs ou atributos que nos indique uma resposta mais adequado ao seu caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código esta comentado explicando o seu funcionamento.

```js
//String com o html
var html = '<input type="text" name="fname"><input type="text" name="fname"><input type="text" name="fname"><br>dfsdfs sdf sdf sdfsd fsdf sdfd sdfsfds';

//Coloca a string com o html dentro de uma div de uma forma que o jquery consiga manipular como se estivesse selecionado algum elemento da pagina
var $html = $('<div />',{html:html});

//Pecorre todos os elementos do tipo "text" dentro da selecao
$html.find('[type="text"]').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('name', i);//Coloca a numeracao a cada elemento
});

//Joga o html na div "inputs" que criei como exemplo
$('#inputs').append($html.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
</div>
```

Comment: valeu, funcionou!